# REST services in ColdFusion 11

Tags: rest, coldfusion

I am trying to create a new rest service in coldfusion and I wanted to try not passing in some parameters if I don't have a value for them but I am getting a 'not found' response from my function.

REST Service CFC:

```
 <cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/crudService">       
        <cffunction name="getHandlerJSON" access="remote" httpmethod="GET" restpath="{customerID}" returntype="query" produces="application/json">
            <cfargument name="customerID" required="false" restargsource="Path" type="numeric" default=-1/>

                <cfset myQuery = queryNew("id,name","Integer,varchar",[[1, "Sagar"], [2, "Ganatra"]])>
                <cfquery dbtype="query" name="resultQuery">
                    select * from myQuery where 1=1
                    <cfif arguments.customerID neq -1>
                        and id = #arguments.customerID#
                    </cfif>
                </cfquery>

            <cfreturn resultQuery>

        </cffunction>
    </cfcomponent>
```

And this is how I am calling it:

```
<cfhttp url="http://dev.test.com/rest/api/crudService/2" result="restResult" method="GET" />

<cfdump var="#deserializeJSON(restResult.filecontent,false)#">
```

And the outcome:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ID","NAME"],"DATA":[[2,"Ganatra"]]}
```

What I want to do is to be able to call my service without an id and get all of the results back. Do I need to create a separate function for this? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

When passing parameters to a REST service CFC via PATH those params must exist in the URL.  If not, then the path CF is looking at is not correct.

I believe you will need a separate function to return all results...OR, pass a huge number like 1000000.